# Native ads in UITableView with multiple sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, mopub

I have integrated mopub-ios-sdk native ads for UITableView from this [guide](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/wiki/Native-Ads-Integration) in my application. It works fine only for my first section, but doesn't work for other sections. On server i added repeat value. How can I fix this problem?

P.S. this [pull request](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/pull/125) haven't helped for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a dirty hack for current version **mopub-ios-sdk(3.9.0)**. You can post your data(repeat value, and fixed path) on your server and then work with methods from class MPClientAdPositioning.

```
- (void)addFixedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (void)enableRepeatingPositionsWithInterval:(NSUInteger)interval;
```

You must independently calculate indexPath for your UITableView, where you insert your native ads. Here you need these methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections;

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

It was helpful for me. Maybe someone know better solution?